# How to adapt a horizontal listView vertically in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm new to UWP development. Now I just implement a horizontal listView. Here is my code:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource DefaultBackground}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Height="100" Grid.Row="0"/>

    <controls:TestListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyListView" IsItemClickEnabled="False" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Folders}" Margin="10,0,10,0"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:TestClass">
                <controls:TestControl/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="270"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </controls:TestListView>

</Grid>
```

I want the `MyListView` take up all space vertically. Notice that the `TestControl`(UserControl) is another ListView. It may contains plenty of items. The final result is that the height of `MyListView` is equal to the maximun height among all the `TestControl`. I wish the `TestControl` should to display a scrollbar instead of just showing a long list vertically, but it didn't.

So how to make the height of all `TestControl` adaptive to the height of the 
UWP application?

Comment: Position an horizontal anchor point, vertically, where you want and position the listView according to the anchor point.

Comment: If I'm understanding your intent correctly, change where you have your setter for `VerticalContentAlignment` from `Top` to `Stretch` as well as adding the same to the parent control (`ListView`)

Comment: Instead of Editing the Question, If you post it as an answer, it will be helpful.

Comment: @ChrisW. this was genius, it is important to set the  `ListViewItem` content alignment or the content doesn't stretch. So a big thankyou but this is would have been a better answer, OP left this out of theirs

Comment: @ChrisSchaller ah thanks, always cool seeing something from years past still helping folks! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got what I want. Just make the following change, everything is fine.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="270" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
                         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" 
                         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```